# Android: How to deactivate GPS

Tags: java, android, gps

'm working on an android app, and i'm quite new to the android development.
At the moment i have problems to find a way to deactivate the GPS on the device.

What i'm trying to do is to deactivate the GPS when the user clicks a button. As far as i know the only way to do is buy using removeUpdates method from the LocationManager. But my problem is atm that this method awaits the LocationListiner as a parameter. But i don't know how to get the LocationListiner :/

Here is my code:

The following code is part of the onCreate of my MainActivity

```
 Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Startet die Abfrage der GPS Position
            final LocationManager mLocMan = GetMyLocation();

            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create(); //Read Update
            alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Signal");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Some message");

            alertDialog.setButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    mLocMan.removeUpdates();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show(); 
        }

    });

private LocationManager GetMyLocation(){
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    GetLocation getMyLocation = new GetLocation();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, getMyLocation);

    return locationManager;
}
```

Maybe someone has a hint for me. At the moment i have still some problems wrapping my head around the android system :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement somewhere the LocationListener to be able of receive the updates via onLocationChanged(Location location).

And then, you juste have to locationManager.removeUpdates(MyLocationListener);

You can use the activity to implements the listener and then
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
...

LocationManager manager;
GetLocation listener;

@Override
    protected void onCreate() {
manager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
listener = new GetLocation();

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        manager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }
```

Comment: I have class where i implement the LocationListener

`public class GetLocation implements LocationListener {
    private Activity activity;

    public void GetLocation(Activity _activity){
        this.activity = _activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        String myLocation = location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude();

        MainActivity.textViewToChange.setText("Position " + myLocation);
    }
`

Comment: Then you need to pass the instance of this class to the method RemoveUpdate. The easiest is to create the instance in the oncreate of the activity/fragment. Usually, I keep the reference of the locationmanager and the locationlistener in the screen class. From that, it's easy to stop and start the listener.

***I've edited my code***